# Join in unix when field is numeric in a huge file

Tags: sorting, unix, join, numeric

So I have two files. `File A` and `File B`. `File A` is huge (>60 GB) and has 16 rows, a mix of numeric and strings, is separated by "|", and has over 600,000,000 lines. Field 3 in this file is the ID and it is a numeric field, with different lengths (e.g., someone's ID can be 1, and someone else's can be 100)

`File B` just has a bunch of ID (~1,000,000) and I want to extract all the rows from `File A` that have an ID that is in `File B'. I have started doing this using Linux with the following code

```
sort -k3,3 -t'|' FileA.txt  > FileASorted.txt
sort -k1,1 -t'|' FileB.txt  > FileBSorted.txt

join -1 3 -2 1 -t'|' FileASorted.txt FileBSorted.txt > merged.txt
```

The problem I have is that `merged.txt` is empty (when I know for a fact there are at least 10 matches)... I have googled this and it seems like the issue is that the join field (the ID) is numeric. Some people propose padding the field with zeros but 1) I'm not entirely sure how to do this, and 2) this seems very slow/time inefficient.

Any other ideas out there? or help on how to add the padding of 0s only to the relevant field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first sort file b using the unique flag (-u)

```
sort -u file.b > sortedfile.b
```

Then loop through sortedfile.b and for each grep file.a. In zsh I would do a

```
foreach C (`cat sortedfile.b`)
    grep $C file.a > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $C >> res.txt
    fi
end
```

Redirect output from grep to /dev/null and test whether there was a match ($? -eq 0) and append (>>) the result from that line to res.txt.

A single > will overwrite the file. I'm a bit rusty at zsh now so there might be a typo. You may be using bash which can have a slightly different foreach syntax.